# Print Enum Value

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to print the name/second value of the selected enum, but I only managed to print the identifier/first value of the item.
By selected I mean the enum is displayed in a panel and what is selected there.
This is how I did that:

```
print(bpy.context.scene.printenum)
```

This is my enum prop:

```
bpy.types.Scene.printenum = bpy.props.EnumProperty( items=[('A', "Apple", ""), ('B', "Lemon", ""), ('C', "Orange", "")], name="")
```

With this method, it either prints "A", "B", or "C", but that's not what I want. I'd like to print either "Apple", "Lemon", or "Orange".
What would be the way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach to achieve your goal is by accessing the data via the bl_rna of your enum variable.

```
import bpy

bpy.types.Scene.printenum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    items=[('A', "Apple", ""), ('B', "Lemon", ""), ('C', "Orange", "")],
    name="",
    )

scn= bpy.context.scene

items = scn.bl_rna.properties['printenum'].enum_items


print(f"item [ identifier ] : {items[scn.printenum].identifier}")
print(f"item [ name ] : {items[scn.printenum].name}")
print(f"item [ description ] : {items[scn.printenum].description}")
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: Note that this won't work if your enum property items are fetched via a callback. In which case you can use this solution https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269715/86891

Comment: Thank you @Gorgious for the additional information. Is that method works for displaying the items as "label(text=...)" and the text based on each item selected enum values (still Apple, Lemon, Orange)?

Comment: Well if I understood correctly @Tsybe you can still get the information by testing the value of the enum and checking if it's the same as the first item of the list of tuples returned by that method. `next((t[1] for t in items_callback(self, context) if t[0] == context.scene.printenum))` or something like that I haven't actually tested

Comment: I didn't exactly mean it that way. I want to display per item. I created a topic about it if you could take a look at it: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/285402/display-enum-name-for-items